# How do I hack VSCode to inject my own scripts or styles in devtools?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, trusted-types

When I try this in the Chrome Devtools in a VS Code window,

```js
const s = document.createElement('script')
s.src="https://unpkg.com/lume@0.3.0-alpha.25/dist/global.js"
```

it results in this error:

```
This document requires 'TrustedScriptURL' assignment.
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'src' property on 'HTMLScriptElement': This document requires 'TrustedScriptURL' assignment.
```

How do I get around this so that I can hack my VS Code locally to do what I want? For example, I want to inject WebGL animations behind my editor text, or other fun local experiments.

Comment: related: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web.dev/issues/4139

Comment: can you not achieve what you want by [writing an extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension)? if not, explain why.